# Add backToApplication link after KeyCloak successful password change

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

When a user is requested to update his/her password via the forgot password operation, he sees a change password page when he/she clicks on the reset link received via email.

After the form with the new password is submitted a page with the following content is displayed. Which did not include the link for 'back to Application'.

How I can add that ? I've setup respective client 'Home URL' correctly.

[image]